# Emacs change font face in LaTeX mode

Tags: emacs, font-face, emacs-faces

I have a horrible font rendering for verbatim text in Emacs LaTeX mode:

[image]

How to make it black, normal size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M-x customize-face RET tex-verbatim RET`

Answer (score 0):

For Emacs on Windows:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `fixed-pitch` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Click "Show all properties"
3. Uncheck all. Check "Inherit"